# Mysterious "Chart-Encircled" Button in Touch Bar

Tags: touch-bar

[image: Mysterious Button in Touch Bar]

The image shows the mysterious "chart encircled" button in my Touch Bar, on a 2019 MacBook Pro (2 Thunderbolt Ports). It shows four bar-chart-alike bars of varying height in black, on a background of a circle of white. What is it? I press it when it appears, and it simply disappears with no obvious action occurring.

Comment: I don't believe it does; the button pops in no matter which app I am using, without a slider/scrubber control. I use Opera as my main browser, and thus the Safari.app link is a bit of a stretch...

Comment: Does it appear after a fresh restart?  Does it show up when logged into another user account?

Comment: Did things change after terminating "Control Strip" from Activity Monitor?

Comment: Does not appear after freshly restarting.

Comment: Does not immediately re-appear when forcibly quitting “Control Strip” from Activity Monitor.app!